# create new dataframe once time-delta is higher than xy

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with the following scheme:

| time | parameter | TimeDelta |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 800 | - |
| 3 | 788 | 2 |
| 4 | 544 | 1 |
| 7 | 344 | 3 |
| 8 | 244 | 1 |

Is it possible to create new dataframes according TimeDelta? So if TimeDelta is greater than e.g. 1.5, create new dataframe?
So that I have three dataframes as follows:

dataframe1

| time | parameter | TimeDelta |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 800 | - |

dataframe2

| time | parameter | TimeDelta |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 788 | 2 |
| 4 | 544 | 1 |

dataframe3

| time | parameter | TimeDelta |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 7 | 344 | 3 |
| 8 | 244 | 1 |

Comment: Why not loop over the data?

Comment: Loop is also okay. But I am not sure how to do it in a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a custom group and split with `groupby`.

First ensure that your "TimeDelta" values are numeric with `pd.to_numeric`, then asses whether they are geater than 1.5, and apply a cumsum() to flag all the following rows up to the next value above threshold. Finally `groupby` the custom group and convert to `dict`.

```
group = pd.to_numeric(df.TimeDelta, errors='coerce').gt(1.5).cumsum()
my_dfs = dict(list(df.groupby(group)))
```

output:

```
>>> my_dfs
{0:    time  parameter TimeDelta
 0     1        800         -,
 1:    time  parameter TimeDelta
 1     3        788         2
 2     4        544         1,
 2:    time  parameter TimeDelta
 3     7        344         3
 4     8        244         1}
```

accessing a particular group:

```
>>> my_dfs[1] # second group
   time  parameter TimeDelta
1     3        788         2
2     4        544         1
```

looping over the dataframes:

```
for group, df in dict(list(df.groupby(group))).items():
    print(f'group {group}')
    print(df)
```