# Label all following rows once value is greater than xy

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe in the following format:

| time | parameter | TimeDelta |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 | - |
| 2 | 456 | 1 |
| 4 | 122 | 2 |
| 7 | 344 | 3 |
| 8 | 344 | 1 |

How to build an additional column with labeling, once TimeDelta is greater than e.g. 1.5?
And also apply this labeling for the following rows once TimeDelta is again greater than 1.5?

| time | parameter | TimeDelta | Label |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 | - | 1 |
| 2 | 456 | 1 | 1 |
| 4 | 122 | 2 | 2 |
| 7 | 344 | 3 | 3 |
| 8 | 344 | 1 | 3 |

I do not want to loop over every row, which is extremely slow.
Maybe it is possible with cumsum() to flag all the following rows up to the next value above threshold?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [create new dataframe once time-delta is higher than xy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69295626/create-new-dataframe-once-time-delta-is-higher-than-xy)

Comment: @jezrael IMO it is, OP just had to use the `group` variable

Comment: @mozway - added to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use part of soluton from [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69295626/create-new-dataframe-once-time-delta-is-higher-than-xy), add `1` and assign to new column:

```
df['Label'] = pd.to_numeric(df['TimeDelta'], errors='coerce').gt(1.5).cumsum().add(1)
print (df)
   time  parameter TimeDelta  Label
0     1        123         -      1
1     2        456         1      1
2     4        122         2      2
3     7        344         3      3
4     8        344         1      3
```

Comment: Very elegant, thanks. This already answers my question. 
Is it also possible to start with Label id like e.g. 10?
10, 11, 12

Comment: @AdlerMüller - Can you test `.add(10)`  instead `.add(1)` ?