# Labeling according TimeDelta in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe with the following structure:

| time | parameter_1 | TimeDelta |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | - |
| 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 4 | 1 | 2 |
| 5 | 1 | 1 |
| 7 | 1 | 2 |
| 8 | 1 | 1 |
| 14 | 1 | 6 |
| 15 | 1 | 1 |
| 17 | 1 | 2 |

Now I want to label according time.
Labeling starts with 1.
if time delta is only 1, no increase should take place in labeling .
if timedelta is greater than 1 but less than 6, the label should begin with 1 and then count up to 3.
If the distance is 6 or greater, then the labeling is done again at 1. here too, the label is again up to 3. and so forth. is it possible without a loop or how can I best do it? maybe it will be more understandable if you see the table as follows:

| time | parameter_1 | TimeDelta | Label |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 42 | - | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 4 | 1 | 2 | 2 |
| 5 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 7 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 8 | 1 | 1 | 3 |
| 14 | 1 | 6 | 1 |
| 15 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 17 | 1 | 2 | 2 |

I already asked a similar question see: [Label all following rows once value is greater than xy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69296996/label-all-following-rows-once-value-is-greater-than-xy)
However, the labeling has not been repeated here or it does not start again at 1 if the distance is greater than xy.
Any ideas? Thanks.

in fact I have time series data. which repeat themselves after a period of 6 seconds:
[image]

Edit2:
When I use the code of Quang Hoang, the labeling looks as follows:

[image]

```
import pandas as pd

data = [[1, 1, 0], 
        [2, 1, 1], 
        [4, 1, 2],
        [5, 1, 1],
        [7, 1, 2],
        [8, 1, 1],
        [14, 1, 6],
        [15, 1, 1],
        [17, 1, 2],
       ]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['time', 'parameter_1', 'TimeDelta'])

blocks = df['TimeDelta'].ge(6).cumsum()
labels = df['TimeDelta'].gt(1.5)
df['label'] = labels.groupby(blocks).cumsum()


df
```

Answer (score 1):

The approach should be pretty similar: you identify the block of label first, then identify the labels within blocks:

```
blocks = df['TimeDelta'].ge(6).cumsum()
labels = df['TimeDelta'].gt(1)
df['label'] = labels.groupby(blocks).cumsum()
```

Comment: Thanks for editing your answer. However there is a small problem.
In the first cycle there are the labels 0, 1 and 2.

In the second cycle it starts with 1 (1, 2, 3..)

Comment: @AdlerMüller change labels to `~df['TimeDelta'].le(1)`